# Does the reader understand that the mixing up of addresses comes before the mistake with mixed past simple?

Tags: past-tense

Munster records told me that they made a mistake in our orders .In fact they mixed up both addresses. They sent my record to you and your record to me so you have received mine and I 'm going to receive yours

I know I already asked this question but I think my question was not well asked
that is why I am re asking it.

Does the reader understand that the mixing up of addresses comes before the mistake with mixed past simple .

I think my problem is because the mixing up of addresses is the mistake. Both actions are almost simultaneous however the discovering happened after the mixing up that is why I thought past perfect could have been better for mixed.

Comment: Try adding a bounty before posting a duplicate.

Comment: The second sentence simply clarifies what the mistake was - it doesn't imply that one happened before the other.

Comment: This reader doesn’t understand the question at all. For me, “the mixing up of addresses” is an event in the world being discussed (the world of orders and deliveries), whereas “the mistake with mixed past simple” is an event in the discourse world (the world of the person who is doing the discussing). So it is nonsensical to talk about one’s coming before the other.